# Linux Redhat Command Execution via executable files

Tags: linux, terminal, executable, redhat

How can i execute commands in terminal via an executable file. We can realize this in windows with .bat files. Does linux redhat provide the same?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. Use [BASH](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_%28Unix_shell%29), the shell common to most Linux distributions. You will find the ["Advanced BASH scripting Guide"](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/) useful.